# Надо ли ставить Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Будет около 100 товаров без фильтрации и сортировки.

Онлайн оплаты не будет. Просто в карточке товара будет попап который отправит заказчику на е-майл письмо с данными.

Я думаю создать Custom Post type и через него выводить. Не будет слишком большая нагрузка в 100 записей для Custom Post Type? Сайт будет работать на VDS

Comment: Если нет покупок - это просто витрина, вукомерц не нужен

Comment: Не надо. И ВПС нафик не нужен. Простой шаред за пару баксов будет даже лучше.

Comment: 100 записей - это просто ни о чём.

Comment: А вообще ответ на вопрос лежит в иной плоскости. Не используйте непойми какие хостинги. На любом нормальном хоть 100, хоть 500 товаров на WooCommerce будут работать с той же скоростью, что и сделанный на коленке сайт с Custom Post Types. А, скорее всего, даже быстрее.